# Custom Exception output regardless of if statement

Tags: java, exception

I'm trying to get the person's name from an input prompt. Get the name length and if the length is less than 1 throw a custom error throws LineLimitException, and prompt the user again to enter their name. I know I threw a lot of code in here but I'm hoping it makes what I'm trying to do more clearly.

LineLimitException Class

```
     public LineLimitException(String message){
           super(message);
     }
    }
```

Here I prompt and store the name field

```
            name = input.nextLine();
            int strSizeName = name.length();
            if(strSizeName < 1) {
```

```
I'm getting these results in the console
How many employees are there?
2
Enter employee 1's name
Name must be greater than one character. Please try again.
Enter employee 1's name  *<--- this is before I can even enter a name*
Enter employee's hourly wage *<-- prompts for hourly wage before I got the name.*
```

```
public class Driver {
    
    /**
     * defualt constructor
     */
    public Driver() {
    }

    /**
     * Main method - prompts the user for name, hours worked, and hourly salary. Stores it in a person object
     * @author 
     * @param args
     * 
     */
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws LineLimitException{
        ArrayList<Employee> person = new ArrayList<Employee>();

        // prompt user for the total number of employees
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many employees are there?");

        String name;
        int numEmployees = input.nextInt();

        for (int count = 1; count <= numEmployees; count++) {
            System.out.println("Enter employee " + count + "'s name");


            **name = input.nextLine();
            int strSizeName = name.length();
            if(strSizeName < 1) {
                //Why is this showing up afterI give emploee count?
                System.out.println("Name must be greater than one character. Please try again.");
                //reprompt the user for a name
                System.out.println("Enter employee " + count + "'s name");
            }else {
                continue;
            }**
            
            
            System.out.println("Enter employee's hourly wage");
            double wage = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter how many hours worked");
            double hrsWkd = input.nextDouble();

            person.add(new Employee(name, wage, hrsWkd)); // add an employee object to the ArrayList
            printSalaryReport(person, wage, hrsWkd);
        }
        input.close();
        System.out.println("CSV File Created.");
    }

    /**
     * Method printSalaryReport - prints the employee person objects name, hours worked
     * hourly salary and gross salary to a csv file.
     * @param person in ArrayList
     * @param getHours_Worked 
     * @param getHourly_Salary 
     * @throws IncorrectFileNameException 
     */
    private static void printSalaryReport(ArrayList<Employee> person, double getHours_Worked, double getHourly_Salary) {
        String CSV_SEPARATOR = ",";
        String fileName = "employee.csv";
         try
            {
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileName), "UTF-8"));
                String Header = "Name, Hourly Salary, Hours Worked, Pay";
                bw.write(Header.toString());
                bw.newLine();
                
                for (Employee man : person)
                {
                    StringBuffer manStr = new StringBuffer();
                    manStr.append(man.getName());
                    manStr.append(CSV_SEPARATOR);
                    manStr.append(man.getHourly_Salary());
                    manStr.append(CSV_SEPARATOR);
                    manStr.append(man.getHours_Worked());
                    manStr.append(CSV_SEPARATOR);
                    manStr.append(calculateSalary(man.getHours_Worked(), man.getHourly_Salary()));
                    bw.write(manStr.toString());
                    bw.newLine();
                }
                bw.flush();
                bw.close();
                
            }
            catch (IOException err){}
            
    }

    /**
     * Method calculateSalary takes the hours worked and hourly salary and returns
     * the result of each multiplied.
     * 
     * @param getHours_Worked
     * @param getHourly_Salary
     * @return
     */
    private static Object calculateSalary(double getHours_Worked, double getHourly_Salary) {
        double salary = getHourly_Salary;
        double hoursWorked = getHours_Worked;
        double wkAmount = salary*hoursWorked;
        return wkAmount;
    }

}
```

Comment: When you throw uncatched exception, you program ends so you do not need throw that if you want user to specify name anyway. Prompt for input in loop, print diagnostic if error and ask again.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what I need to do

Comment: you wrote: "if the length is less than 1 throw a custom error throws LineLimitException, and prompt the user again to enter their name". So, you need ask user to input the name in a loop without throwing any exception because when you throw that, main method will be terminated and program will end.

Comment: That's not good. my Assignment wants us to create a custom exception and use it. Having the whole program stop isn't what I was hoping for

Comment: But you wrote exactly that:  public static void main(String[] args) throws LineLimitException. So, if you throw this exception anywhere within your code, program will exit with error massage and stack dump. If you want to manage that, you must catch exceprion when it will be thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    boolean skip = false;
    for (int count = 1; count <= numEmployees; count++) {
        if (!skip)
            input.nextLine();
        else
            skip = false;

        try {
            System.out.println("Enter employee " + count + "'s name");

            name = input.nextLine();
            int strSizeName = name.length();
            if (strSizeName < 1)
                throw new LineLimitException("Name must be non-empty. Please try again.");

            System.out.println("Enter employee's hourly wage");
            double wage = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter how many hours worked");
            double hrsWkd = input.nextDouble();

            person.add(new Employee(name, wage, hrsWkd)); // add an employee object to the ArrayList
            printSalaryReport(person, wage, hrsWkd);
        } catch (final LineLimitException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            count--;
            skip = true;
        }
    }
```

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: This is great but I need to show I'm using a custom Exception.

Comment: Edited one more time. Now the exception is constructed with a message.

Comment: Doesn't solve my problem. The console shows all question right after the how many employee prompt is done. This is the console output: `How many employees are there?
1
Enter employee 1's name
Name must be greater than one character. Please try again.
Enter employee 1's name`

Comment: I think it works correct. The program tries to get a valid name before asking for another information.

Comment: It should ask for the name, check it, if not 1 display message. But only if the name has one character in it. From the launch of the program all the input prompts write to console. I need them to occur one at a time

Comment: Isn't an 1-character-name considered as valid? And what should the program do if the user enters an empty name?

Comment: ...And I have changed the 2-nd line. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo.

Comment: I wanted to do an empty line, but the console window keep making carriage returns until a name is given

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you

Comment: No problem. :-)

Comment: Edited the answer so after throwing LineLimitException the method nextLine() will not be called (it would be at least redundant).